# Inspiration from Hacktoberfest

Tags: feature-request

[Hacktoberfest](https://hacktoberfest.digitalocean.com/) is a program to get programmers involved in the open source community. The idea is that by contributing to a number of projects during the month of October, members can receive a free t shirt and stickers. Would a similar reward system possibly work on Chemistry StackExchange? What about giving some sort of reward to new contributors who accumulate a certain amount of reputation over a short period of time? While many people might join the community, contribute enough to get the rewards and leave, such a system could draw new long term users to Chemistry StackExchange.

Comment: They already sent swag to the 72 top participants of the site. It contained a T-shirt, a mug, and some stickers.

Comment: ^^true, but that was rewarding the people who essentially built the community. I like the idea, but since chem.se is not one of the top priorities in the network, I don't think they'll do it.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but I am sure that this could be done with something as simple as stickers. I don't know how the entire SE structure works, though.